# QT5 list all dirs and files in windows 7 or higher

Tags: windows, qt

I have problem with list all files from C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc for example.
There is about 400 items. I see only 10.
I find, that problem is in QT5, and that I must developed this in microsoft visual studio.

But I can't believe it.

I have the next code:

```
    QDir dir(path);
    dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::Dirs | QDir::Hidden);
    foreach(QFileInfo item, dir.entryInfoList() )
    {
        qDebug() << "Item: " << item.baseName();
    }
```

Exist some solution in QT5? Solution, where I get all 400 items.

PS: Of course. I runing it as administrator and I am working on 64bit system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm...
The problem is only in 32bit applications. When I make 64bit build, at this moment I see all 400 files.

My mistake. Solution is everywhere on internet :-).